# Oracle SQL Developer not inserting XML in XMLTYPE via loading file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ubuntu-16.04

There is a table with a **XMLTYPE** column `(NOT NULL)`, XML (string) can be inserted using SQLPLUS  but  SQL Developer inserts **'null'** when XML is loaded from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround:- Set **XMLTYPE** column `nullable`
, insert `null` first time , `COMMIT` and insert XML after that.